# Парсим изображения с сайта

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Есть сайт с разметкой вида

```
<div class="block"><img src="image.png" class alt="Название" /> Бла бла бла</div>
<div class="block"><img src="image2.png" class alt="Название" /> Бла бла бла</div>
<div class="block"><img src="image3.png" class alt="Название" /> Бла бла бла</div>
```

Мне нужно спарсить и вывести на экран изображения. На сайте 3 изображения. У меня для каждого изображения создан отдельный ImageView
Вот мой вариант кода, который, якобы должен получить изображения:

```
Elements imgs = doc.select("div.trade img");

for (Element img : imgs) {

    Element myImage = img;
    String imgSrc = myImage.attr("src");
    InputStream inp = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
    // Decode Bitmap
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inp);
    allImages.add(bitmap);

}
```

В этом коде на строку

```
allImages.add(bitmap);
```

Ругается Eclipse:

> allImages cannot be resolved

Так вот, как мне передать полученное изображение в компонент `ImageView` - `@+id/imgv1`?

Comment: А что это за объект allImages? Какого класса? ImageView? Вообще программный доступ к компоненту из разметки получается методом (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgv1) для твоего случая

Comment: @Werder Простите, я в Android не очень то разбираюсь. Я web разработчик. Не могли бы вы немного подробнее ?

Comment: Файл разметки хранит у тебя ImageView, и для того чтобы работать с ним в коде, нужно создать объект вот такой строчкой: ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgv1);

Comment: Теперь ты можешь вставить в этот ImageView свой рисунок, методом: imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: @Werder сделал так `Elements imgs = doc.select("div.trade img");

for (Element img : imgs) {

Element myImage = img;
String imgSrc = myImage.attr("src");
InputStream inp = null;
 try { inp = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inp);
  allImages.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`  - сделал так. после парсинга - вылетает - в приложении произошла ошибка

Comment: А что за ошибка? В какой строке? Глянь что написано в стеке

Answer (score 1):

У тебя в  `String imgSrc` хранятся url ссылки на image.png (типо "http://examle.com/image.png" , но нужно еще добавить baseUrl (http://examle.com/))

Тебе нужно их изначально скачать с интернета, сохранить в Bitmap а потом уже добавлять в `allImages`
используй [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) вот код для получения Bitmap по ссылке

```
Target target = new Target() {
          @Override
          public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                // тут bitmap - это и есть твоя картинка , которую нужно добавить в `allImages`
                   allImages.add(bitmap);
              }

          @Override
          public void onBitmapFailed() {
          }
   }

   Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
```